# How to resolve authentication parameter with Spring messaging RSocket @ConnectMapping

Tags: spring, spring-messaging, rsocket

```java
@ConnectMapping("setup")
public void setup(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
}
```

```java
@MessageMapping("hello")
public void hello(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
}
```

The two mappings are on the server side.

When the RSocket client setup a connection with 'message/x.rsocket.authentication.v0' metadata,

and then send request to `hello` mapping.

The first principal is null.

The second principal is the expected authentication data.

How to resolve the principal in @ConnectMapping?

Answer (score 0):

Work properly with `spring-security-rsocket` version `5.3.4.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add message handler with custom resolver which will include `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` from package `org.springframework.security.messaging.handler.invocation.reactive`

may need to add dependency

```
org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging
```

to your maven/gradle

my example for kotlin:

```
@Bean
fun messageHandler(strategies: RSocketStrategies?): RSocketMessageHandler? {
    val handler = RSocketMessageHandler()
    handler.argumentResolverConfigurer.addCustomResolver(AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver())
    handler.rSocketStrategies = strategies
    return handler
}
```